# Pandas as_index for keeping grouped column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, transform

I'm trying to create a transformed (mean) table grouped by a column. Everything works properly except the grouped column does not stay in the table view. Not sure why using `as_index=False`doesn't work in this case -

```
df2 =df[cols].groupby(by='col1',as_index=False)[['val1','val2','val3']].transform('mean').sort_values(by=['val1'],ascending=False).drop_duplicates()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`transform` assumes the same index as the original data's, so it doesn't bring the grouping key into the picture. Why would you want `transform` just to `drop_duplicates`:

```
df2 = (df[cols].groupby(by='col1',as_index=False)[['val1','val2','val3']]
               .mean()
               .sort_values(by=['val1'],ascending=False)
      )
```